# Event handler exists

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

How can i determine in a web server control (inherited from linkbutton) if an event handler is set for OnClick or OnCommand?

I rather not override the events and set variables... etc

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Thanks mjmarsh but i am doing the check on the prerender event inside my control so something like "If mybase.OnClick isnot Nothing " will not work.

Comment: Why not Orry? Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Inside Page_Load or after:

if (ctrl.OnClick != null)
{
    // ...
}
```